# Working with a array that changes constantly

Tags: algorithm

Given an array , if 2 adjacent number are equal then they can merge and their value is increased by one. Find the smallest possible number of element left in the array after this process.
Ex: [1,1,1,2,1] ->[1,2,2,1]-> [1,3,1]. Thus the answer is 3.
I have tried using a linked list to store the array then iterate through the whole thing until no equal, adjacent number is detected but this seem very insufficent.
Any hint or suggestion is very appriciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: why doesnt 1,1,1,2,1 become 2,1,2,1?

Comment: It can, just that it is not the smallest possible amount of number. This is a optimization problem.

Comment: what is the size of data?

Comment: The number of element in the array N can be up to 10^5, and a[i] is between (1,10^9)

Comment: I find that if the number of consecutive numbers is even, they can be merged left to right. For example `1, 1, 1, 1` will be merged to `2, 2`. If the number of conservative is odd, we must leave one left either at the end or start or somewhere in the middle. For example `1,1,1,1,1` will be merged to either of these results `1,2,2`, `2,1,2`, `2,2,1`.

Comment: The odd number of consecutive numbers will not help to merge two parts left and right of them. So if they are at the tip, the left out will be the tip. Others merged as even group. Also there is some calculation help to decide to merge to left or to merge to right if the odd group is in the middle.

Comment: And merge from the smallest to biggest.

Comment: If it can is the answer to @ChristianSloper's comment, then your problem is non-deterministic and not consistent. You need to have a rule, how you act, in those cases.

Comment: @Giorgi You are required to minimize the number of remaining elements at the end. [1, 1, 1, 2, 1] -> [2, 1, 2, 1] is allowed but if you do it you are stuck with 4 elements, which is not the least you can get.

Comment: @Cem yes exactly. Excuse me if how I phrased the question was confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution, but I don't know if it is optimal:

Start with the smallest number in the array. In the example [1 1 1 2 1], it is 1. The reason is that you will not get new 1's after merging other elements. So they are easy to work with.

Obviously, if you have an even number of consecutive 1s, merging them all is never subobtimal. So, we need to decide what to do with an odd number of consecutive elements. One of them needs to be left out (not merged), and once we choose that one, remaining parts have both an even number of 1s.

The important observation here is that once you choose the element to be left out, the array to the left of it and the array to the right of it constitute two independent problems. Since there will be a single 1 in the middle, you can't merge any number at the right side with the left side. So, for every possible choice, you can recursively solve the problem for the right- and left-sub-arrays, and then find the minimum result.

### Algorithm

To summarize the method, these are the steps to be followed:

- If the length of array is 0, return 0.
- Find the minimum element in the array. Call it x.
- Go over the array one more time, create a *new array* where even number of consecutive x's are all merged.
- If you saw an odd number of x's anywhere in the array, do this:

  - Let the index of first element be i. For each j = i, i+2, i+4, ... that belongs to the sequence of x's, solve the problem for sub-arrays [0 .. j-1] and [j+1 .. end]. Call their results n1 and n2.
  - Return the minimum n1 + n2 + 1 from these possible splits.
- If you didn't see an odd number of x's, then there are no x's left in the array. Go back to step 1.

Note that you can substitute x's with x+1's in the 4th step, and choose the sub-problem indices accordingly, to possibly save some work in the recursive calls.

### Code

Here is a c++ code that does this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// the range is [start, end)
int
solve(std::vector<int>& array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return 0;

    int length = end - start;

    // find the minimum element
    int min = array[start];
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        if (array[i] < min)
            min = array[i];

    std::vector<int> newArray;
    newArray.reserve(length + 1);
    int minCount = 0; // number of consecutive elements that are equal to min
    int firstOddNumber =
      -1; // index of an odd number of consecutive min's in the new array
    int oddNumbers = 0; // number of min's starting at firstOddNumber

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        // iterate one last time with i == end to run the checks again.
        // hence the special case. we pop this element after the loop.
        int elem = i < end ? array[i] : min + 1;

        if (elem == min) {
            minCount++;
        } else if (minCount != 0) {
            // even number of min's
            if (minCount % 2 == 0) {
                // merge them
                for (int j = 0; j < minCount / 2; j++)
                    newArray.push_back(min + 1);
            } else {
                // do not merge them but save their index in the new array
                firstOddNumber = newArray.size();
                oddNumbers = minCount;
                for (int j = 0; j < minCount; j++)
                    newArray.push_back(min);

                // ^^^ this part could be modified as I wrote in the note in my
                // answer
            }
            minCount = 0;
            newArray.push_back(elem);
        } else
            newArray.push_back(elem);
    }

    // remove the min+1 element pushed when i == end
    newArray.pop_back();

    if (firstOddNumber == -1)
        // no odd number of consecutive min's, repeat the procedure
        return solve(newArray, 0, newArray.size());
    else {
        int minResult = newArray.size();
        // solve two subproblems for each possible split
        for (int i = firstOddNumber; i <= firstOddNumber + oddNumbers; i += 2) {
            int result = 1 + solve(newArray, 0, i) +
                         solve(newArray, i + 1, newArray.size());
            if (result < minResult)
                minResult = result;

            // ^^^ this part could be modified as I wrote in the note in my
            // answer
        }
        return minResult;
    }
}

void
test(std::vector<int> v, int expected)
{
    int result = solve(v, 0, v.size());
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    if (result == expected)
        std::cout << "CORRECT\n" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "EXPECTED: " << expected << '\n' << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
    test({ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 }, 3);
    test({ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 2);
    test({ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 2);
    test({ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 }, 3);
    test({ 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 }, 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you and this seem really sufficient as well, i learned alot !!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the question requires reading the input from the end, instead of the start. Because if it required reading from the start then your second iteration must have been : [2, 1, 2, 1]

Assuming the question requires reading the input from the end, here's the solution:

Here's the algorithm:

- Add all the elements to stack 1. Stack1: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]; result:[] and top = 1;
- Checking if  1 and 2 are equal, if not equal adding it to the result stack. result: [2, 1]
- Checking if 1 and 1 are equal, if they are, incrementing the element and pushing the element to stack 1, and also adding all the result stack elements to stack1. Stack1: [1, 2, 2, 1], result: [].
- Repeating the process until stack1 is empty.

  class Solution {
  public int mergeAdjacentSimilarElements(int[] arr) {
  //stack 1
  Stack stack = new Stack<>();
  //stack 2
  Stack result = new Stack<>();

  ```
            //add all the elements to the stack, as stack follows LIFO, the last element would be at the top
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                stack.push(arr[i]);
            }

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                int top = !stack.isEmpty() ? stack.pop() : -1; // assign -1 in case stack is empty
                int temp = !stack.isEmpty() ? stack.peek() : -1; // assign -1 in case stack is empty

                //if top and temp are equal
                if (top != -1 && temp != -1 && top == temp) {
                    stack.pop();

                    //increment the value of the top, and add it to stack
                    stack.push(++top);

                    //check if there are any elements in the result stack, 
                    // as they have to be added to stack1, as stack1 is modified.
                    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                        stack.push(result.pop());

                    }
                } else {

                    //else simply add the element to the stack.
                    result.push(top);
                }
            }

            //for testing
            result.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

            return result.size();

        }
  ```

  }

Comment: This solution is too abitrary i think, it is only correct with the example i have put out. Reading input from beginning or end shouln't really matter.

Comment: Try `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`